# Meaning of the Parable of the Talents

Tags: parables, money, liberal-christianity

I’m wondering what people think of this interpretation of sermon of the [Parable of the Fearful Investor](http://docplayer.net/36377175-As-well-as-for-every-other-good-idea-in-this-sermon-louisville-westminster-john-knox-press-1994-152.html).

I’ll provide this one example, but I have others if you'd like. The interpretation I usually see elsewhere, including with this forum, is that it is about investing to get something back, using money as a metaphor for your gifts. This interpretation gets to be a problem, and most preachers will tell you this, when the 3rd servant says the master is “hard” and reaped where didn’t sow. The parable doesn’t refute that and it has the master saying he should have taken interest on the money, which would be against Jewish law, so I just can’t map the master on to God.

As the link suggests, “Read the parable like someone living on a lake in Nicaragua or one of the “little ones” who followed Jesus around…”. Then, the lesson comes from the 3rd servant. He doesn’t play the capitalist’s game of exploitation and profit for profit’s sake. Yes, he’s cast out, but it’s cast away from the world that Jesus rejects in the rest of the gospels.

Comment: It looks as if your preacher there is looking for a way to stand out and be sensational.

Comment: Isn't everything related to religion opinion based?  The experts do not agree on so many points.  The brand name religions disagree on so many things.  There are no facts and logic involved just faith and opinions.

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely ridiculous to claim the Master isn't God/Jesus as it is in the other parables of the same nature (e.g. Mt 18:23,35; 24:44,46 etc). Not to mention that the wicked and worthless servant goes to Hell. Since interest/money refer to literal money, and the parable isn't talking literally about money but something spiritual (grace, spiritual gifts, skills), interest means Jesus coming back to find the grace given believers to be put to good use (Mt 7:19; Jn 15:1-2,6). That is, the spiritual gifts given the believer should return intact, and even more adundant, since they should convert more people, show good example, bring more people to Christ etc.

Comment: This is not an isolated sermon. He has a footnote to William Herzog's book which contains many references to others who have this same interpretation. I expected better dialog than "ridiculous". The question of whether the servant is correct about the master or master is correct about the servant is not answered by the parable, it depends on interpretation. For me, having the master be correct requires ignoring too much context. For example, where else in the Bible do we find money being used as a metaphor for spiritual gifts? And if he meant hell, why didn't he say hell?

Answer (score 1):

The linked sermon seems to be doing very little serious work with the passage itself and is mainly being used as a pretext for the preacher to express her economic opinions.

The parable of the talents very clearly likens the master to God. As Sola Gratia correctly points out, the parable ends with the servant sent to Hell which would be absurd in the parable if the master is not supposed to be likened to God. The comment about the unlawfulness of moneylending is also a stretch. For one, the commandment was to not be a moneylender to the "my people who are poor" (Exodus 22:25) and probably excluded gentiles and the non-poor engaging in some kind of capital investment. More importantly, parables themselves never map exactly onto God's nature or what is right and wrong. Take for example Luke 16:1-9, where Jesus seems to be approving of a manager's dishonest accounting while short-timing, something clearly sinful. Jesus is not commending the sin, but the shrewdness.

Focusing on what the passage really teaches, it comes immediately after the parable of the Ten Virgins. The point of that parable is to always be ready for the master to return by preparing in advance. The parable of the talents takes a different nuance to the theme: always be ready for your master to return by being diligent with what is entrusted to you. This clearly implies financial stewardship, but it more generally applies to generic "fruit bearing". If you are the holy seed when the gospel rain waters your good soil, bear fruit with it or you will be cast off.

Comment: Don't sermons frequently relate Biblical stories to the present and apply their lessons?

Comment: Yes, they do. I think that applications about stewardship can be appropriate.

Comment: Either of us could be correct, but I would not call your interpretation "using as a pretext".

Comment: If the point is to be ready for God to return, I think this parable is saying to look at who you are doing business with. I don't see anything that supports that "the outer darkness" is Hell. Instead, everything shows men using their ill-gotten gains to get more, with no concern for community. The "outer darkness" then is where Jesus spent most of his time, with the poor, the ones who lived day to day, but also supported each other and gave of what little they had.

Comment: The sermon links to Occupy Wall Street in the notes and specifically criticizes capitalism including associating the 1% (an Occupy Wall Street argument) with those who are not relegated to the outer darkness. None of this is native to the text. This is why I consider it to be a pretext.

Comment: Capitalism was not an ideology at the time, but are you arguing that Jesus did not support the poor, did not support the ideas of welcoming people into community and helping them or that he didn't oppose the Pharisees who were working with the Roman powers? I thought we already covered that you can use parables to relate to modern times.

Comment: Indeed, the parables are meant to be applied at all times prior to Jesus returning. My contention is that the preacher did not come to this text and discover within it Jesus' love for the poor and an economic theory criticizing landowners and rent-seeking. She brought her prior beliefs about economic justice and has placed them in Jesus' mouth.

Comment: I can see why you think that, and I'm sure it's easy to think that since this is probably the first time you've heard it, but this is just my favorite sermon on the topic. There are others, and there is scholarship supporting it. I'm not a scholar, and I'm not going to do a thesis on this, so I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

For context’s sake, I’ve provided the actual passage containing the parable below. Sola Gratia’s answer covers the topic of the master’s identity well, so I won’t say much on that front. I’d like to address your comment about moneylending. The servants themselves were not necessarily lending money. As you put it, their returns depended on how the bank they put their money in fares. The bank most likely lent money to foreigners, as was permitted by Mosaic law. See Deuteronomy 23:19-20 (NASB), for example:

> 19 “You shall not charge interest to your countrymen: interest on money, food, or anything that may be loaned at interest. 20 You may charge interest to a foreigner, but to your countrymen you shall not charge interest, so that the Lord your God may bless you in all that you undertake in the land which you are about to enter to possess.

While Jews could not charge other Jews interest, they were free to lend to and collect interest from any foreigners. Jews did this then, and it’s what they became known for around the world over time. The master was not punishing the third servant for not sinning, only for being too scared to use the gifts he was given.

—-

> 14 “For it is just like a man about to go on a journey, who called his own slaves and entrusted his possessions to them. 15 To one he gave five talents, to another, two, and to another, one, each according to his own ability; and he went on his journey. 16 Immediately the one who had received the five talents went and traded with them, and gained five more talents. 17 In the same manner the one who had received the two talents gained two more. 18 But he who received the one talent went away, and dug a hole in the ground and hid his master’s money.
>   19 “Now after a long time the master of those slaves came and settled accounts with them. 20 The one who had received the five talents came up and brought five more talents, saying, ‘Master, you entrusted five talents to me. See, I have gained five more talents.’ 21 His master said to him, ‘Well done, good and faithful slave. You were faithful with a few things, I will put you in charge of many things; enter into the joy of your master.’
>   22 “Also the one who had received the two talents came up and said, ‘Master, you entrusted two talents to me. See, I have gained two more talents.’ 23 His master said to him, ‘Well done, good and faithful slave. You were faithful with a few things, I will put you in charge of many things; enter into the joy of your master.’
>   24 “And the one also who had received the one talent came up and said, ‘Master, I knew you to be a hard man, reaping where you did not sow and gathering where you scattered no seed. 25 And I was afraid, and went away and hid your talent in the ground. See, you have what is yours.’
>   26 “But his master answered and said to him, ‘You wicked, lazy slave, you knew that I reap where I did not sow and gather where I scattered no seed. 27 Then you ought to have put my money in the bank, and on my arrival I would have received my money back with interest. 28 Therefore take away the talent from him, and give it to the one who has the ten talents.’
>   29 “For to everyone who has, more shall be given, and he will have an abundance; but from the one who does not have, even what he does have shall be taken away. 30 Throw out the worthless slave into the outer darkness; in that place there will be weeping and gnashing of teeth.
>   **—Matthew 25:14-30 NASB**

Comment: That was constructive. I'm not clear on where the parable mentions foreigners though.

Comment: @John-Lausten - It doesn’t. Many cultural aspects of that region during that time period were simply common knowledge. The authors of the gospels didn’t explain them because it’s just something everyone knew. Because we didn’t live in that time period ourselves, we sometimes need additional explanation.

Comment: I'm glad we agree that you need context and extra-Biblical evidence to interpret parables. To do that, you would need to use historiography. I've never heard any preacher or theologian say the slaves could have used banks because they were foreigners. I don't see anything in the text that could lead you to that.

Comment: @John-Lausten--I'm not saying that slaves could use banks because they were foreigners, but that by OT law banks could only lend to foreigners because the bankers were Jews. [This website](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/moneylending) shows that Jews did lend money, even to each other, at high interest rates during biblical times. The Scripture in my answer explains why the Jews running the banks lending to foreigners and collecting interest was not illegal by the Pentateuch.